# AMD Raid 5 drive not accessible in windows

Tags: windows-7, raid

I'm running RAID 5 using the onboard AMD RAID controller. 
Until this afternoon I have successfully been running windows, but after a system freeze and reboot, Windows went to system repair. Diskpart reported no drives attached to the system.

Rebooting into the RAID utility, I can see the raid array and it is reported as "Functional".

Rebooting Windows 7 installation asks for a missing driver disk and it also does not display the raid drive

Answer (score 0):

I rebooted into the BIOS and under the SATA configuration changed the OnChip SATA type from RAID to AHCI and rebooted. Windows of course started the system repair utility and I rebooted again. This time I changed the OnChip SATA type back to RAID, saved and rebooted again.

Windows successfully booted and all was right with the world again.